# iterm2 and tmux: Keyboard conflicts

Tags: iterm

When I open a terminal in iTerm2, I can use the command key to make it work like Meta, so that I can for example move between words (e.g. with <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>.

However, as soon as I start a tmux session within the terminal (e.g. by typing `tmux new`, for some reason these bindings don't work anymore, why? and how can I fix it?

### Update

Below is a picture of my iTerm2 preferences:

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the `xterm-keys` window option? Without it *tmux* will recognize `^[[1;5D` as M-Left, but if `xterm-keys` is off it will transmit it as plain Left (i.e. `^[[D` or `^[OD`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the command keys mapped to option in the Keys tab and the option keys set to act as meta in the Profiles tab? If you do, set the option keys to act as "+Esc" in the preferences:

[image]

When the option keys are set to act as meta, they are not recognized in `tmux`.

Edit: `\e[1;5D` and `\e[1;5C` are not recognized by `tmux` either. You could just map ⌘B  to `\eb` and ⌘F to `\ef`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I have that activated already, but I am actually using `Command-f` and `Command-b` to move between words (see my updated edits), so that should not be related.